# PEP 328 "Relative import beyond top level package"

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, package

I have this file setup:

```
mainfolder:
    __init__.py
    mainfile.py
    subfolder1:
        file1.py
        __init__.py
    subfolder2:
        file2.py
        __init__.py
```

I need to import mainfile.py into file1.py and file2.py. Currently I am using:

```
from .. import mainfile
```

However this brings the error: attempted relative import beyond top level package.

I have also tried:

```
from ...mainfolder import mainfile
```

Which brings up the same message, and:

```
from mainfolder import mainfile
```

Which brings the error message: no module named 'mainfolder'

Within the __init __.py files I have this code:

```
__all__ = [list of files in package]
```

I'm not sure why this is not working. I would greatly appreciate it if someone could explain what I am doing wrong.

EDIT: The error "Attempted relative import beyond top-level package" occurred when I ran:

```
from .. import mainfile
```

within file 1.

Comment: Did you call it with ``python mainfolder/subfolder2/file2.py`` or with ``python -m mainfolder.subfolder2.file2``?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: What do you call/import that raises the "attempted relative import beyond top level package" ImportError?

Comment: python mainfolder/subfolder/file2.py

Answer (score 0):

When using packages, Python requires the `__package__` variable be defined to make sense of relative imports.

When you call `python mainfolder/subfolder2/file2.py`, it simply executes `file2.py` like a script - and, without `__package__`, fails to do any relative imports.

When you call `python -m mainfolder.subfolder2.file2`, you're essentially telling Python, "please execute the submodule `file2` in the subpackage `subfolder2` of the package `mainfolder`", so it sets `__package__` for you and everything works fine.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14132789/relative-imports-for-the-billionth-time) for a much more in-depth discussion.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do a relative import above the script being called.
The best way I've found to fix that error when you can't run your scripts as modules is to add `import sys; sys.path += ['../']` at the beginning of the file. This will add the parent directory as one of the locations to look in for modules, so you can then just `import mainfile`. This also works if the module you want to import is somewhere else in your filesystem, just change `['../']` to the relative path pointing to the directory containing the module you want to import.